# Add access control to Mongodb 3.0.3

Tags: mongodb, authentication, database

Currently our Mongodb on the remote Linux server can be connected with a blank username & password. check the picture as below : the client can access it by MongoVUE tool (or a java-based back-end system) with anonymous access.

So how to disable the anonymous access of Mongodb 3.0.3 and set a name/password authentication to the remote Mongo service.

MongoDB version 3.0.3 on CentOS 6.5

[image]

Comment: https://docs.mongodb.org/v3.0/security/ I'm lost in the security part of Mongo official manual...

Comment: Have you created any user in mongodb & started it in auth mode?

Answer (score 0):

Yep, you need to create users in your database ,grant priveleges to them and then restart mongod process with --auth parameter. Note, that in mongo 3.* now using scram sha 1 auth method . I'm not sure that mongovue supports it! 
So another way is leave it in no auth mode , but configure on that server a list of IP that allows to conect on mongo port. Good luck!)